# Web animation css highlight

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I saw this genius animation with text highlight on this website. Does anyone know how to achive this text highlight then delete animation?

https://www.nobledesktop.com/certificates/web-design

Comment: You could look at the text with developer tools.

Comment: It's just splitting the word into different spans and applying a transparent background color. You would have figured if you hit F12 once.

Comment: I don't know whats with people dumbass as you, if someone asks, you got think he tryed to figure it out first. 
If you don't want to help don't go to sites like these and post stupid comments please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window.setTimeout to launch functions at certain times

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
    $('.text').addClass('highlight') 
}, 1000);

setTimeout(function(){ 
    $('.text').text('');
}, 2000);
```

use css :after for the text highlighting and animation.

```
.text{
    font-size: 2em;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.text:after{
    content: "";
    background: #C8C8FF;
    height: 100%;
    width: 0%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    transition: all .5s ease 0s;
    right: 0;
}

.text.highlight:after{
   width: 100%;
}
```

Here it is all together:

http://jsfiddle.net/vzjc3xmr/

Comment: That was fast! Thanks a lot