# How do I achieve this animation using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have been searching how to accomplish the animation on this website using html/css/js/jquery: https://www.nobledesktop.com/certificates/web-design. In particular, I want to know how to achieve the highlighting then deleting effect of the animation, but I also want to know how to insert the next word one character at a time with a delay. This question has been asked before but did not achieve the last specification that I have mentioned above.

This is the thread I am referring to: [Web animation css highlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30444351/web-animation-css-highlight)

This is an image of the animation I'm talking about on http://www.nobledesktop.com/certificates/web-design.

http://pasteboard.co/2ywHhxGE.png

I have looked at the source code related to that span but I have no clue where to start past highlighting the text as answered in the aforementioned thread. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's a bit late and the [jquery.typer.js](https://github.com/layervault/jquery.typer.js) library will probably be the best solution as explained by Marcos, but I have time on my hands right now and I tried to clone the behaviour from the link you are referring to with jQuery and CSS.

Here is my [working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kiirosora/umasoxus/).

I created recursive functions for the typing animation and word traversal, in tandem with CSS transitions for the highlight animation:

**JS**

```
function typify($elem, wordSec, charSec, highlightSec) {
    var texts = $elem.data('type').split(',');
    $elem.css({
        transition: 'background-size ' + (highlightSec / 1000) + 's'
    });
    addByWord($elem, texts, 0, wordSec, charSec, highlightSec);
}

function addByWord($elem, texts, i, wordSec, charSec, highlightSec) {
    if (i < texts.length) {
        var text = texts[i],
            duration = (text.length * charSec);

        $elem.text('')
            .addClass('reset')
            .removeClass('highlight');
        addByLetter($elem, texts[i], 0, charSec);
        setTimeout(function () {
            $elem.removeClass('reset')
                .addClass('highlight');
        }, duration + wordSec);
        setTimeout(function () {
            addByWord($elem, texts, ++i, wordSec, charSec, highlightSec);
        }, duration + highlightSec + 300 + wordSec);
    } else {
        addByWord($elem, texts, 0, wordSec, charSec, highlightSec);
    }
}

function addByLetter($elem, txt, i, sec) {
    if (i < txt.length) {
        var ch = txt.split('')[i];
        $elem.text($elem.text() + ch);
        setTimeout(function () {
            addByLetter($elem, txt, ++i, sec);
        }, sec);
    }
}

typify($('.animation'), 1500, 105, 300);
```

**CSS**

```
.animation {
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #00a8e6;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    display: inline-block;
    background: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0, 20, 255, 0.5) 0%, rgba(0, 20, 255, 0.5) 100%) no-repeat top right;
    background-size: 0% 100%;
}
.animation.highlight {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
.animation.reset {
    background: transparent;
    background-size: 0% 100%;
}
```

The definition of parameters of the function, `typify($elem, wordSec, charSec, highlightSec)` below:

- $elem - jQuery element you want to target (should have data-type with
  values separated by strings.
- wordSec - duration of each word to be shown on screen in milliseconds,
  after being typed and before being highlighted
- charSec - speed of typing animation per letter milliseconds
- highlightSec - speed of CSS highlight animation in milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

They accomplished it by using the [jquery.typer.js](https://github.com/layervault/jquery.typer.js) library. You can take a look at that source and see how it's done.

But in the website you pointed, they have modified the plugin slightly. For instance, they added an option called `highlightEverything`, to avoid the default behavior of selecting only the text that changes between transitions.